# get unsupported python packages in snowflake snowpark python worksheet

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, nltk, snowflake-stage

I am using snowflake python worksheet to perform text analysis on some data in a snowflake table. This includes lemmatizing the text

I created this function in snowflake python worksheet

```
def lemmatize_text(text):
    # Initialize NLTK's WordNet Lemmatizer for lemmatization
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(text) 
    lemmatized_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words]
    return ' '.join(lemmatized_words)
```

It gives me an error that the word_tokenize is not a known member of nltk
I suppose it is not supported directly in the snowflake anaconda packages

How can I solve this problem?

I am new to snowflake and snowpark, in my jupyter notebook, i tried to create a udf and put it on the snowflake stage, but i dont know what do next.

> from snowflake.snowpark import Session
> session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
> from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf, sproc, col
> from snowflake.snowpark.types import IntegerType, FloatType, StringType, BooleanType, Variant
> from snowflake.snowpark import functions as fn
>
> session.sql("CREATE STAGE IF NOT EXISTS nlp_text_analysis").collect()
>
> def lemmatize_text(session : Session, text: str) -> Variant:
> import nltk
> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
> import re
> nltk.download('punkt')
> nltk.download('wordnet')
> nltk.download('omw-1.4')
>
> lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
> words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
> lemmatized_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words]
> return ' '.join(lemmatized_words)
>
> session.sproc.register(func=lemmatize_text, name="lemmatize_text", replace=True)

result: <snowflake.snowpark.stored_procedure.StoredProcedure at 0x1ddd9888850>

Comment: Are you sure you are importing it from the right package? Looking at [this](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) it should be `from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize` and I don't see that in your code. This doesn't seem related to Snowflake but to the way you're doing the import.

Answer (score 0):

try rolling back the spacy package version to 3.5.3 - that helped me using the nlp modules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).